# Name bus in Altium

Tags: altium

I want to  use  I2C Bus as shown in the figure
[image]

my question is how should I name the Bus itself the problem that I have that Net labels as shown in the doc like  LED0 LED1...    which would mean that bus name LED[0..9].

thanks for any hint !

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by writing the name like this:

BUSNAME:signalA[1..10],signalB,signalC

Then when you label the BUS it will appear "BUSNAME" and not all the signals.

Comment: This does not seem to work in Altium 17.1; BUSNAME:A[1..10],B,C shows up as exactly that entire text, and hovering over  the bus just shows the net name as "BUSNAME:A[1..10]" (without B or C)

Answer (score 1):

The Altium concept of busses differs from Mentor or other CAD systems. In Altium a bus is a bundle of nets following the same naming pattern : 
"[Name][NumericalIdentifer]" 
Example: ADDR0, ADDR1, ADDR2 ... etc. can enter the bus ADDR[0..n]

http://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADRR/Sch_Obj-Bus((Bus))_AD

For your purpose you have to use harnesses as you did in your schematic. This concept can group nets with different net labels following no naming pattern.

http://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADOH/Using+Signal+Harnesses